# Sci-fi book about a company that made human clones that use photosynthesis to defeat world hunger

Tags: story-identification, books

I believe the book is about a protagonist who finds a tape of their deceased parent. Their alive parent works for the same company that killed their parent.

When the protagonist started to look into the company, the company killed the other parent and searched for the protagonist. The protagonist went into hiding whilst also conducting research.

The protagonist tracked down a facility where the company is conducting their secret project. When infiltrating the facility the protagonist discovers the project to be a goal to end world hunger. The company was creating humans that could use photosynthesis to self sustain without additional resources.

The protagonist fell in love with one of the experiments. Whilst gathering intel to whistle-blow the protagonist comes into contact with the creator of the project. A chair-ridden man who’s seeking a new body host to live on but masks his goal with propaganda.

The protagonist flees the grasp of the creator with their intent to not leave their love behind. The protagonist escaped with their lover and unambiguously disappeared whilst releasing the information unanimously.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you recall what the cover art looked like?

Comment: For that last word, did you maybe mean universally?  Simultaneously?  Maybe ubiquitously?  I'm having a hard time parsing "unanimously."

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis I think they mean anonymously.

Comment: Are you sure it's a full book?  I can think of 2 stories offhand where people were given the ability to photosynthesize: "Village of the Chosen" by Alan Dean Foster and "The Green Leopard Plague" by Walter Jon Williams.  (Also in Scalzi's *Old Man's War* series, but it's not really plot-relevant.)

Comment: Adam Robert's *By Light Alone* is about people genetically engineered for photosynthesis through their hair, but takes place after this has become the norm.

Comment: And Frank Herbert's _Greenslaves_. There are loads of novels and stories about humans with chlorophyll, but the murder of the parents and corporate elements in this are distinctive.

Comment: Could be a garbled version of *Oryx and Crake* by Margaret Atwood?